# Parfor in Matlab with recursive function

Tags: matlab, recursion, parfor

I have a problem with `parfor` in Matlab. I have read this http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel-for-loops-parfor.html but I am not able to understand how to fix my code. I think there is a problem with the recursive nature of the function `Inv`. Could you help me?

Here a simplified version of the code

```
R=10;
max_rec=10^3; 
n=20;
set(0,'RecursionLimit',max_rec+4); %set the maximum number of recursions
Res=zeros(R,1);

parfor s=1:R
    XY = unifrnd(0,1,n,2);
    Z=zeros(n,1);
    for p=1:n
        x1=XY(p,1);
        x2=XY(p,2);
        Z(p)=Inv(x1, x2, max_rec);
    end
    Res(s)=sum(Z,1);  
end

function t=Inv(x1,x2,iter)
t = 0;
if iter > 0
      if x1<0.5
         if x2<0.5
            t=(0+Inv(2*x2, 2*x1, iter-1))/4;
         else
            t=(1+Inv(2*x1, 2*x2-1, iter-1))/4;
         end
      else
        if x2>=0.5
           t=(2+Inv(2*x1-1, 2*x2-1, iter-1))/4;
        else
           t=(3+Inv(1-2*x2, 2-2*x1, iter-1))/4;
        end
      end     
end
end
```

Comment: Recursion and parallelism are like oil and water. They don't work together.

Comment: @rayryeng unless you add dish soap

Comment: @rayryeng mustard works as well